# SwiftUI: Hierarichal, Selectable List

Tags: core-data, swiftui, relationship, hierarchical-data

I've been working on a problem for the last couple of days and I can't seem to figure out how to approach it.

I'd like to achieve an **hierarichal system** of material-groups where the leaf would be a specific material.
I basically have **two CoreData entities**, `Material` and `MaterialGroup`.
 `MaterialGroup` has 3 relationships: `subGroup` (MaterialGroups that belong to a specific MaterialGroup), `superGroup` (the inverse of subGroup) and `subMaterial` (the leaf of the hierarchy).

The ideal scenario which I'd like to accomplish is a **selectable list** of `MaterialGroups`, for every selection I'd have 3 options:
**(1)** - Create `MaterialGroup` on the same level of the hierarchy  
**(2)** - Create `subGroup` for selection
**(3)** - Create a `Material` for `MaterialGroup`

A the moment I can create these hierarchies but I cannot display them, I just have a plain selectable list with no depth. I cannot figure out how to make the lists expandable and selectable at the same time. 
Kind of like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NwJC.jpg).

I've also wondered how to then select the `Material` when I worked my way to a leaf. If I were to use something like `List(materialGroupArray, selection: $materialGroupSelection)`, I couldn't select the `Material`.

I'd be grateful for any tips. 
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach for a hierarchical list:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

class Material {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class MaterialGroup: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var subGroup: MaterialGroup?
    let subMaterial: Material?

    init(id: String, subGroup: MaterialGroup?, subMaterial: Material?) {
        self.id = id
        self.subGroup = subGroup
        self.subMaterial = subMaterial
    }
}

let group1 = MaterialGroup(id: "G1",subGroup: nil, subMaterial: Material(name: "M1"))
let group2 = MaterialGroup(id: "G2",subGroup: nil, subMaterial: Material(name: "M2"))
let group3 = MaterialGroup(id: "G3",subGroup: group2, subMaterial: nil)
let group4 = MaterialGroup(id: "G4",subGroup: group3, subMaterial: nil)

let demoData: [MaterialGroup] = [
    group1,
    group4,
    MaterialGroup(id: "G5",subGroup: nil, subMaterial: Material(name: "M5"))

]

struct GroupView: View {
    let group: MaterialGroup
    @State var showChildRow = false
    @State var selected = false

    var hasChildren: Bool {
        group.subGroup != nil
    }

    var displayName: String {
        if let material = group.subMaterial {
            return material.name
        } else {
            return group.id
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if hasChildren {
                Image(systemName: showChildRow ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.right")
            }

            Text("\(displayName)").font(.caption2)
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
        .transition(.scale)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(selected ? Color.red.opacity(0.1) : Color.black.opacity(0.1)))
        .onTapGesture {
            if hasChildren {
                withAnimation {
                    showChildRow.toggle()
                }
            } else {
                // You could use a closure here
                // onSelect: (Material) -> Void
                selected.toggle()
            }
        }

        if hasChildren && showChildRow {
            GroupView(group: group.subGroup!)
                .padding(.leading)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(demoData) { group in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    GroupView(group: group)
                }
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```